# asp menu control

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

I'm working on an ASP app and I have an asp menu item

It shows the menu sub-items when the mouse is over but i'd like it to show the sub-items with a mouse click

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible, but it is an extremely bad idea to do. You would have to modify the javascript completely.

Instead I highly recommend you to create your own menu control. You can get the SiteMap through the `SiteMapDataSource`.

- [SiteMap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemap.aspx)
- [SiteMapDataSource class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemapdatasource.aspx)